# Pandas manipulate dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, data-manipulation

I am querying a database and populating a pandas dataframe. I am struggling to aggregate the data (via groupby) and then manipulate the dataframe index such that the dates in the table become the index.
Here is an example of how the data looks like before and after the groupby and what I ultimately am looking for.

dataframe - populated data

```
firm |    dates    | received | Sent
-----------------------------------------
A       10/08/2016      2         8
A       12/08/2016      4         2
B       10/08/2016      1         0
B       11/08/2016      3         5
A       13/08/2016      5         1
C       14/08/2016      7         3 
B       14/08/2016      2         5
```

1. First I want to Group By "firm" and "dates" and "received/sent".
2. Then manipulate the DataFrame such that the dates becomes the index - rather than the row-index.
3. Finally to add a total column for each day
4. Some of the firms do not have 'activity' during some days or at least no activity in either received or sent. However as I want a view of the past X days back, empty values aren't possible rather I need to fill in a zero as a value instead.

> ```
> dates        | 10/08/2016 | 11/08/2016| 12/08/2016| 13/08/2016| 14/08/2016    
> firm  |  
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> A      received     2           0            4            5          0
>        sent         8           0            2            1          0
>
> B      received     1           3            1            0          2
>        sent         0           5            0            0          5
>
> C      received     0           0            2            0          1
>        sent         0           0            1            2          0
>
> Totals r.           3           3            7            5          3             
> Totals s.           8           0            3            3          5
> ```

I've tried the following code:

```
df = > mysql query result

n_received = df.groupby(["firm", "dates"
                                ]).received.size()

n_sent = df.groupby(["firm", "dates"
                                ]).sent.size()

tables = pd.DataFrame({ 'received': n_received, 'sent': n_sent,
                           }, 
                            columns=['received','sent'])

this = pd.melt(tables, 
                    id_vars=['dates', 
                             'firm',
                             'received', 'sent']

this = this.set_index(['dates', 
                         'firm',
                         'received', 'sent'
                    'var'
                    ])        
this = this.unstack('dates').fillna(0)     

this.columns = this.columns.droplevel()

this.columns.name = ''

this = this.transpose()
```

Basically, I am not getting to the result I want based on this code. 
- How can I achieve this?
- Conceptually is there a better way of achieving this result ? Say aggregating in the SQL statement or does the aggregation in Pandas make more sense from an optimisation point of view and logically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stack`(`unstack`) to transform data from long to wide(wide to long) format:

```
import pandas as pd
# calculate the total received and sent grouped by dates
df1 = df.drop('firm', axis = 1).groupby('dates').sum().reset_index()

# add total category as the firm column
df1['firm'] = 'total'

# concatenate the summary data frame and original data frame use stack and unstack to 
# transform the data frame so that dates appear as columns while received and sent stack as column.
pd.concat([df, df1]).set_index(['firm', 'dates']).stack().unstack(level = 1).fillna(0)

# dates         10/08/2016  11/08/2016  12/08/2016  13/08/2016  14/08/2016
#  firm                     
#     A     Sent       8.0         0.0         2.0         1.0         0.0
#       received       2.0         0.0         4.0         5.0         0.0
#     B     Sent       0.0         5.0         0.0         0.0         5.0
#       received       1.0         3.0         0.0         0.0         2.0
#     C     Sent       0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         3.0
#       received       0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         7.0
# total     Sent       8.0         5.0         2.0         1.0         8.0
#       received       3.0         3.0         4.0         5.0         9.0
```